how to use multiple model in single serializer or how to make combined serializer but not extended approch
i'm  implementing API in which i have to store data in multiple database table and i can not change the schema , so here i have implement the serializers by multiple inharite approch.
here is my serializers:

class Organization_1_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=..., **kwargs):
        super(Organization_1_Serializer, self).__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Organizations
        fields =  "__all__"

class Organization_2_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=..., **kwargs):
        super(Organization_2_Serializer, self).__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        model = Organization_2
        fields = "__all__"


class OrganizationSerializer(Organization_1_Serializer, Organization_2_Serializer):

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=..., **kwargs):
        super(OrganizationSerializer, self).__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)


    

i want to create POST api in which i can simple pass the resquest.data to the OrganizationSerializer and serializer will manage the things according to the model.
my concern to use ModelSerializer instead Serializer that single api contain 3-4 tables fields and each table has the appox 20-25 columns to manage. using serializers.Serializer or accept ModelSerializer it's becoming so complex. please help me to solve this issue aur suggest right approch to do so.
Thank you in advanced
